# How to get a new mesh with modifiers applied using Blender Python API?

Tags: python, mesh

I've been scouring the Blender Python API docs for a way to get access to the mesh data that is displayed in the view-port. (with modifiers applied - WYSIWYG)

---

For reference, this was possible with the 2.4x API's `Mesh.getFromObject` method.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The option to apply modifiers is common for exporters included with Blender, so you can check how they do it.

Typically you can use the [`Object.to_mesh`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.to_mesh) function, which returns a new mesh. You can manipulate it without distructively editing the user's data.

```
import bpy

# --- setup variables ---
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

# assume we have an object with geometry, nurbs, metaball, curves... _not_ a lamp
obj = context.object

# --- get a mesh from the object ---
apply_modifiers = True
settings = 'PREVIEW'
mesh = obj.to_mesh(scene, apply_modifiers, settings)

# ... do something with the mesh ...
```

It's important to remove the mesh, unless you have explicitly assigned it to an object. Otherwise it will be stored in Blender until the file is saved and loaded again.

```
# optionally remove it
bpy.data.meshes.remove(mesh)
```

Comment: Usually the research goes easily, finding an equivalent process in Blender 2.5+, from Blender 2.4.  But sometimes these methods are moved to different classes, and that adds much time, and sometimes really impairs my progress by relying upon the community (not that it's a bad thing, after doing my homework). Thank you for your help!

Comment: I did not need to calculate the tessfaces, so I set the extra parameter calc_tessface=False and my tests pass. Awesome.

Comment: @Tom Pace, only if you want to use legacy access to face data (tris/quads, no ngons) - http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/info_gotcha.html#info-gotcha-mesh-faces

Comment: Doesn't work for new versions anymore

Answer (score 18):

It appears that the [to_mesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.80/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=to_mesh#bpy.types.Object.to_mesh) function no longer has an "apply_modifiers" argument in Blender API 2.80. Instead, you will need to retrieve the dependencies graph ("depsgraph") and use it to get the "evaluated" object:

```
depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
obj = context.object
object_eval = obj.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
```

The new, evaluated object will have a mesh with the modifiers applied. If needed, you can make a copy of it via:

```
mesh_from_eval = bpy.data.meshes.new_from_object(object_eval)
```

for some examples and further info, see:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Depsgraph.html

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146559/how-do-i-get-a-mesh-data-block-with-modifiers-and-shape-keys-applied-in-blender