# Blender scripting: Subdivided vertices with Catmull-Clark

Tags: python, scripting, mesh

In Blender2.73, I have a model with Catmull-Clark Subsurf modifier. How can I get and set the XYZ positions of subdivided vertices(the red circles) in Python Script?

[image]

Alternatively, Can I save the model as just a high polygon model without Subsurf modifier?

Comment: if you are familiar with python: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7196/how-to-get-a-new-mesh-with-modifiers-applied-using-blender-python-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7196/how-to-get-a-new-mesh-with-modifiers-applied-using-blender-python-api) already answers how to apply a modifier; if you still get the parameters of a modifier, here's how:

```
import bpy

for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    for mod in ob.modifiers: 
        if mod.type == 'SUBSURF':
           print("Subsurface modifier (\"%s\") in object \"%s\", with view level %s and render level %s." % (ob.name, mod.levels, mod.render_levels))
           bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier=mod.name)
```

The above script will print to the console the level of all *Subsurface* modifiers in all selected objects, and their names.
Then it will apply the modifiers, so that you can get the coordinates of each vertex.

Comment: thanks! but... sorry, I hope to translate the xyz locations of subdivided vertices individually. So I want to know how to get and set the position.

Comment: On, ok; pretty sure you have to apply the modifier, then