# How to use the result of a modifier stack to create a new object?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

Is there a quick way to copy the result of a modifier stack to create a new object, like if you manually duplicated an object with a modifier stack and applied all the modifiers?

---

Note, It's possible through the Python API: [How to get a new mesh with modifiers applied using Blender Python API?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7196/how-to-get-a-new-mesh-with-modifiers-applied-using-blender-python-api)
But I was wondering if there's a way to do this without Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by converting everything to a mesh.

Object -> Convert -> To Mesh

In the operator options you may want to enable *Keep Original* (so as not to replace the existing objects).