# How to apply a several modifiers with python (but not necessarily all modifiers)?

Tags: python, modifiers

Apply modifier button will write this into the console:

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Box Right ")
```

Adding this line after "bool_mod.object = obj" does not work as expected stating that object has not attribute 'modifier'

ERROR:

```
  File "C:\Users\info\Desktop\Boolean.blend\ui_panel_simple.py", line 38, in execute
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'modifier_apply'
```

CODE:

```
def execute(self, context):   

    target_obj = bpy.context.active_object
    tool_objs = [obj for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects if obj != target_obj]

    for obj in tool_objs:
        bool_mod = target_obj.modifiers.new(obj.name+' ', 'BOOLEAN')
        bool_mod.operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
        bool_mod.object = obj
        target_obj.modifier_apply(modifier=bool_mod.name)
```

I went to blender python website to read about the modifier command and values and to my surprise found nothing that explains what options there are for operation for example.

https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_70_5/bpy.types.Modifier.html

Comment: This will be applied to the active object , so make sure your target object is active before applying the modifier ( set it active through script  each iteration)

Comment: You should use the first line bpy.ops.object.apl......

Comment: figured it out in my answer

Answer (score 9):

*Objects* don't have a `.modifier_apply()`, you can't do `active_object.modifier_apply()`. That's what the main Error message is saying.

`modifier_apply` is an operator of `bpy.ops.object`, which works if there's an active object. Confused? :)

```
# pick any object
obj = bpy.data.objects['Suzanne']

# set the object to active
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj

# this operator will 'work' or 'operate' on the active object we just set
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="my_modifier_name")
```

In the event that you want to apply a subset of modifiers, you have to start applying from the bottom up. You could put checks in place to skip certain modifier by `type`, but in your case you have only *Boolean_Modifiers*.

```
import bpy

def execute(self, context):   

    target_obj = context.active_object
    tool_objs = [o for o in context.selected_objects if o != target_obj]

    BOOL = 'BOOLEAN'
    # first add them.
    for obj in tool_objs:
        bool_mod = target_obj.modifiers.new(name='diff_' + obj.name, type=BOOL)
        bool_mod.operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
        bool_mod.object = obj
        obj.hide = True

    # then apply them individually.
    for modifier in target_obj.modifiers:
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=modifier.name)


execute(None, bpy.context)
```

This is one way to apply the modifier, there is also a direct way to apply all modifiers at once to the Mesh without such a loop. See this [answer for details](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7196/how-to-get-a-new-mesh-with-modifiers-applied-using-blender-python-api?rq=1)

Comment: `bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj` doesn't work; fails with `AttributeError: bpy_prop_collection: attribute "active" not found.` -- Maybe it changed in 2.80?

Comment: yes, answer is correct for `blender version <= 2.79 `

Answer (score 5):

The trick to make this run is that the () after the modifier_apply() cannot be empty. The moment you define the modifier name it works.

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=bool_mod.name)
```

I assume the modifier_apply command is just in this case working like a generic apply command because we are working of a list. But you still have to call out the modifier with the name I assume.

Comment: it's not about that it is because the object doesn't have a method called `modifier_apply()`  so you can't do this `target_obj.modifier_apply()`  instead you have to make your object active and call the operator `bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply()`

Comment: bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply() only works when you call out the modifier to also apply!

Comment: yes but he has it like this `target_obj.modifier_apply()` which is not the same as this  `bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply()` , is it ?

Comment: True - initially I tried "bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply()" first and then exchanged parts with target_obj but still kept the () empty.

Comment: yes it shouldn't be empty