# How to remove/apply all modifiers of one object in python

Tags: python, modifiers

Lets assume you have 1 object with 4 modifiers added to it.
I am curious how one would approach the task to apply all or to delete all modifiers of a just selected object that has many modifiers already added.

The console reads out the modifier delete as

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(modifier="Box Right ")
```

So "Box Right " I might have to replace with something like active.object.modifier.name and then work each modifier off?

This would be very helpful when you want to generate a static mesh for animation or 3D printing.

Comment: related, very: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7196/how-to-get-a-new-mesh-with-modifiers-applied-using-blender-python-api?rq=1

Comment: Ok let me try to figure this own. thank you!

Comment: A short way to apply and remove **all** modifiers on the active objects is `bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')` this is the operator called when using *Alt-C -> Mesh from curve*

Answer (score 16):

### Modifier removal

To remove a modifier from an object.

`obj` below is a reference to an object either obtained via

```
obj = bpy.context.active_object
obj = bpy.context.object
# or
obj = bpy.data.objects[name]
```

If you want to remove a modifier it is done by name, not by type. You could have multiple array modifiers, but only want to remove
a specific one.

```
modifier_to_remove = obj.modifiers.get("Bevel")
obj.modifiers.remove(modifier_to_remove)

# or as a one-liner
obj.modifiers.remove(obj.modifiers.get("Bevel"))

# or remove all modifiers from an object
obj.modifiers.clear()
```

### Modifier Apply

**Using an operator**

As sambler pointed out

```
# operates on all selected objects (not just the scene's _active_object_)
bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')
```

**lower level**

If you want to apply all modifiers it's covered here: [How to get a new mesh with modifiers applied using Blender Python API?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7196/how-to-get-a-new-mesh-with-modifiers-applied-using-blender-python-api?rq=1) - This involves using `obj.to_mesh` and there are a few things to consider, it:

- generates a new mesh from your current `obj` (leaves current `obj.data` intact)
- does not remove the modifiers automatically from the object. (unlike the *Apply* button on the Modifiers panel, or *Convert to Mesh*).

This snippet will:

```
"""
- make a reference to the current obj.data ( i call it old_mesh)
- make a new Mesh ( new_mesh) using the effect of the combined modifiers on `obj`
- remove all modifiers from `obj`
- assign the new Mesh to obj.data 
- remove old_mesh from the blend
"""
```

in code:

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
obj = context.object

# get a reference to the current obj.data
old_mesh = obj.data

# settings for to_mesh
apply_modifiers = True
settings = 'PREVIEW'
new_mesh = obj.to_mesh(scene, apply_modifiers, settings)

# object will still have modifiers, remove them
obj.modifiers.clear()

# assign the new mesh to obj.data 
obj.data = new_mesh

# remove the old mesh from the .blend
bpy.data.meshes.remove(old_mesh)
```

Comment: modifiers.clear() is really great.  i used to remove modifiers sequentially, but if you have many modifiers it can cause the whole stack to update per removal.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with the SURFACE_DEFORM mod? Also related to this, is there are way to bind a surface deform mod without  bpy.ops.object.surfacedeform_bind()?