# Bind and apply SURFACE_DEFORM modifier without bpy.ops?

Tags: python, mesh, modifiers, geometry

Is there a way to bind a surface deform mod without running

```
bpy.ops.object.surfacedeform_bind(modifier="Surface Deform")
```

and is there way to apply it without running

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Surface Deform")
```

The `obj.to_mesh()` method [described here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44514/how-to-remove-apply-all-modifiers-of-one-object-in-python), does not seem to work for Surface Deforms.

Thanks, I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `obj.to_mesh()` method _"not seeming to work"_

Comment: @batFINGER It tutned out I had to do a scene.update() before apply the mod, as the surface deform was added by code via modifiers.new(). Still looking for a way to do the bind without the bpy.ops

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I had to do a [`scene.update()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.update) before applying the modifier, as the surface deform modifier was added by code via `modifiers.new()`.

*I'm still looking for a way to do the bind without the `bpy.ops*` however.*